# Split Columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a problem, I'm trying to split [this column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwQHP.png) from a pandas dataframe in to two seperate columns 'Date' and 'Names'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember: 1) include your sample data as text, 2) include your expected output, 3) show your work so far.

Comment: Please don't paste images or links. Also, please describe the question better.

Comment: With a question this vague, the only answer we can give is "You're doing it wrong.  Do it the right way instead".

Comment: Also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm going to read the guide. Next time I will describe my question better.

Comment: @adrc11 Just read the guide and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are always 10 characters long, use the `str` accessor:

```
df['Date'], df['Names'] =  df['col'].str[:10], df['col'].str[10:]

                        col        Date           Names
0  2020-02-15Kennedy-Harris  2020-02-15  Kennedy-Harris
1     2020-01-28Sanders LLC  2020-01-28     Sanders LLC
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your date format is fairly static. "2020-01-01FirstName, LastName". Unclear what language you're using, but you could pretty easily grab the first 10 characters into one col then the rest into the 2nd.